# "Refreshing" asynchronous page every n seconds inside while loop

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to let my page "refresh" asynchronous (I'm refreshing a div element which contains a partial view) while `var edit = true`. edit is altered when i click my button which has class: btn. I'm wondering where i should put my code.

Should i put my while loop inside my $(document).ready?
I'm kind off lost because this is ALL new to me.

This is my code:

```
var edit = true;

while(edit){
    window.setInterval(function(){
      alert('5 seconds');
    }, 5000);
}

$(document).on('click','.btn', function(){
    if(edit ? edit = false : true);
}
```

Comment: I'll update my question

Comment: What has `if(edit ? edit = false : true);` to do with your question? Even the `alert` has nothing to do with it. In fact, I fail to see what any of this code has to do with your question?

Comment: Also, you have MVC in your tags, but the question doesn't reference that. Are you using Angular or something similar?

Comment: My project is a MVC ASP.NET application, if that doesn't fall under mvc feel free to edit :) im a newbee

Comment: Javascript doesn't work like this. It is single thread language, your `while` loop will never break.

Comment: `I'm trying to let my page "refresh" asynchronous` What do you mean??? Nothing in your posted code is relevant to this

Comment: @A.Wolff update my question, im trying to refresh the div inside my page which contains a partial view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a `while` for a continous refresh. Just use `clearInterval` whenever you clicked the button and restart it on next click.

```js
var interval, i = 0;

$('button').click(function() {
    if( interval ) {
        interval = clearInterval(interval);
    }
    else {
      interval = setInterval(function() {
          console.log(++i);
      }, 1000);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>start / stop</button>
```

As edit to your comment, to start the interval directly I would encapsulate it into a function and use it. Maybe somehow like this:

```js
var interval, i = 0;

function startInterval() {
    if( !interval ) {
        interval = setInterval(function() {
            console.log(++i);
        }, 1000);
    }

    return interval;
}

// start on document load
$(startInterval);

// start / stop on button click
$('button').click(function() {
    interval = interval ? clearInterval(interval) : startInterval();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>start / stop</button>
```

Comment: the button works, thank you! In this code the interval returns true when the button is click for the first time, can i copy `interval = setInterval(function() {
          console.log(++i);
      }, 1000);` into my `$(document).ready` to start the timer once the page is loaded, and will my button still work after that?

Comment: I've added an example with start on page load for you @Roy_Dorsthorst

Comment: seems to be buggy once you click it several times

Comment: Yes, I've missed the `return` in the function. My fault. ;) @Roy_Dorsthorst

Comment: Works like a charm, accepted as answer. Thanks a bunch

Comment: Glad it worked for you! I've made another change and added a `if( !interval )` inside the function to prevent the race condition, whenever a user click on the button bevore the page was loaded. Otherwise it would be possible to have two simultanous intervals. This should fix it. @Roy_Dorsthorst

Answer (score 0):

Below shall refresh the page every while (example: 30 seconds)

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">
...
</head>
```

Comment: I don't think OP is asking about a full page refresh.

Comment: I'm sorry my question wasn't clear enough, my fault. I'm trying to refresh a partial view inside a div element in my current view.